# Include fields on an LDAP user search?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, sssd

I am running an Authentik instance with an LDAP provider/outpost. To test it out, I've bound an Ubuntu server with sssd to the LDAP server. Everything is working great (...finally).

But I am curious if I can add a known field to the LDAP search parameters? Such as the `fullname` field provided by Authentik?

For example:

I can run `id myusername` and get back

```
uid=2001(john.smith) gid=2001(john.smith) groups=2001(john.smith),16434(grp-foo),35262(grp-bar)
```

I can also run `id domain.tld\myusername` or `id myusername@domain.tld` and they all return the same result. All of these are variations of a username and/or domain. But I can also search for the email field, which could be anything, like `id johnsmithrockz@gmailisfake.com`.

What I'd like to attempt is something macOS-like where you can just enter your full name, and it still maps to a valid account. Ex: `id "John Smith"`. But doing that yields:

```
id: ‘John: no such user
id: ‘Smith’: no such user
```

In the `sssh.conf` man pages, I found the setting `re_expression` that lets you add or change the regex match that translates all the possibilities above into a valid user and/or domain combination. By default, it's set to:

```
(((?P<domain>[^\\]+)\\(?P<name>.+$))|((?P<name>[^@]+)@(?P<domain>.+$))|(^(?P<name>[^@\\]+)$))
```

This regex takes care of `domain\name`, `name@domain`, and `name`. Noticeably absent is the email field.

If `sssh` can search for the email field, than it can search for any field, correct? If so, how can I add a search field to sssh in Ubuntu?

I initially tried building a regex out that would transform the name `John Smith` into the username `john.smith`, but that assumes the username and full name are always one-to-one. Therefore the only real option to accomplish this (albeit unnecessary) task is to add an LDAP search field.